# TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple when including another urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-1.11

I’ve read carefully the several other questions that cover this topic, however, none depict the case of include() (including another urls.py file).  I’ve also looked at 1.11 documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher) and coded in accordance, however, I continually get the error “TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().”  Tried just about every derivation of this and the other two answers to no avail.  Where is my mistake/misunderstanding?

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^atfl/', include('atfl.urls'), namespace="atfl"),
]
```

Code in atfl/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from atfl.views import home, people

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'home', name='home'),
    url(r'^people/$', 'people', name='people'),
]
```

Code in atfl/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('atfl/home.html', {})

def LoadTextFile(request):
    return render_to_response("atfl/people.html", {})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error isn't from the `include`, it's from strings `'home'` and `'people'` in the urls.py that you are trying to include. Use the views that you are already importing:

```
from atfl.views import home, people

app_name = 'atfl'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^people/$', people, name='people'),
]
```

Once you've fixed that, there is a bug in your `include` that you should fix. The namespace is an argument to `include`, i.e. `include('atfl.urls', namespace='atfl')`. You have it as an argument to `url()` instead. However, in this case, you should remove the namespace from that URL pattern completely, and add `app_name` to the app's urls.py as above.

```
url(r'^atfl/', include('atfl.urls')),
```

Finally, don't use `render_to_response`. It's obsolete. Use `render` instead.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'atfl/home.html', {})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use strings in atfl/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from atfl.views import home, people

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^people/$', people, name='people'),
]
```